# Is it possible to update <th> with an observable in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, html-table, observable

I'm creating a scheduler using Angular 7, I'm using a regular HTML table.
Datas inside this table are provided through Firebase and are updated perfectly when I add or remove an appointment.
But when I change the week, the header of my HTML table is not refreshing with new dates.

I implemented a rxjs Observable on my data source table (Array of Date)

Component:

```
<table class="tableweek">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="header_time"></th>
      <th class="header_week" *ngFor="let day of tabDays">{{ day | weekday }}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr *ngFor="let hour of tabHours; let i = index">
      <td class="col_time">{{hour | hourFormat}}</td>
      <td class="col_week" *ngFor="let day of tabDays; let j = index" id="h-{{j}}-{{i}}" (click) = "newAppointment(modalAppointment, j, i)">

      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

.ts:

```
 import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
 import { of } from 'rxjs';

 .....

 tabDays: Date[] = [];
 tabDaysObs: Date[] = [];

 ngOnInit() {
  initTabDays();
 }

initTabDays() {
  this.getTabDays().subscribe(dayslist => 
    {
      this.tabDays = this.tabDaysObs;
    }
  );
}

getTabDays(): Observable<Date[]> {
  var dt = new Date(this.currentWeek.date_start);
  while (dt <= this.currentWeek.date_end) {
    this.tabDaysObs.push(new Date(dt));
    dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
  }
  return of(this.tabDaysObs);
}
```

When I update my currentweek, getTabDays is called again but the  is not refreshed.

Is it my code or maybe it is not possible to refresh header of a regular html table dynamically?

Comment: getTabDays() returns a new Observable each time . When you say "update my current week" - you mean you call initTabDays() or just call getTabDays() ? Alternatively you could use a Subject and subscribe to it in init block. Then at each update of week, call next(...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem but I don't know why I had this behavior.

The calendar that I used to select a new date was in my nav bar in another component. I called from the nav bar component a function inside my main component to update my array of date, and it didn't refresh the scheduler.

But when I moved the calendar inside my main component, it worked.

If someone has an idea why...

Answer (score 0):

Try to the following ways

```
initTabDays() {
  this.getTabDays().subscribe(dayslist => 
    {
      setTimeout(()=>{    //<<<---    using ()=> syntax
         this.tabDays.length = 0;
         this.tabDays = this.tabDaysObs;
       }, 0);
    }
  );
}
```